# Why do I need componentWillReceiveProps in this situation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following component code :

```
var Answer = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function(){
        return { comments: []}
  },

  componentWillMount: function(){
        $.ajax({
            context: this,
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/answers/' + this.props.answer.id + '/comments',
            success: function(data){
                this.setState({comments: data});
            }
        });
},

  render: function(){
        return ( 
            <div>
                <Comments comments={this.state.comments} />
            </div>
        );
},
```

Notice how I fetch new state in `componentWillMount`, then pass this new state as props to the `Comments` component. I was expecting that when I `setState` in `componentWillMount`, that would take care of refreshing my `Comments` component and pass the new props, however, it turns out I need this method in my `Comments` component:

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(newProps){
        this.setState({comments: newProps.comments})
},
```

Can someone please explain why when my parent component doesn't update the props that are being passed to its child after I set the paren's state?

Comment: *"however, it turns out I need this method in my `Comments` component"* You only have to do this if you store props in state which seems to be the case here. See  https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html , which I suspect your are doing.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes you are right, I am storing props in state, should I try not to?

Comment: Yes, you should avoid that if you don't have to do it. See the link :)

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks man, that makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are initializing a state in your `Comments` component from the passed props. Initializing a state in a child component that gets changed in a parent component won't re-run the initilizaing code in the child. I'm expecting your `Comments` component `getInitialState` method to look something like this

```
getInitialState: function(){
  return { comments: this.props.comments}
},
```

This method is only called once when `Comments` is initialized so when you pass new props, it wouldn't set the comments to the new ones in `Comments` component unless you used `componentWillReceiveProps`. You shouldn't be making a new state in your child if it's the same as what the parent is providing.

If state is managed only by Answer then delete comments state in your `Comments` component and use it only as props in `Comments`.